# Ruby Blackjack and loops

Tags: ruby, loops, methods, logic, blackjack

I am building a command line ruby blackjack game using methods.  I have gotten to the point where the player can hit or stick (after having being dealt 2 cards). Right now I can't seem to make the jump to thinking logically about how to limit my player to only four hits. make

This tells me that my problem is looping - that is I am approaching the loop part of the program the wrong way.

Here is my code so far:

```
def blackjack
  promt
end

def promt
  puts "Welcome! Would you like to play a game of blackjack? Enter Yes or No"
  play = gets.chomp.downcase
  if play == "yes"
    game_plan
  elsif play =="no"
    puts "That's too bad. Come back when you feel like playing"
  else
    puts "Sorry but I don't understand your respones. Please type and enter yes to play Or no to to quit"
    blackjack
  end
end

def game_plan
  wants_to_play = true
  hand = []
  total = first_move(hand)
  wants_to_play = hit_me(hand)
  if wants_to_play == true
    hit_me(hand)
  end
end

def first_move(hand)
  deal(hand)
  deal(hand)
  total(hand) 
end

def deal(hand)
  card = rand(12)
  puts "You have been dealt a card with a value of #{card}"
  hand << card
end

def total(hand)
  total = 0
  hand.each do |count|
    total += count
  end
  puts "The sum of the cards you have been dealt is #{total}"
  total
end

def hit_me(hand)
  puts "Would you like to hit or stick?"
  yay_or_nah = gets.chomp.downcase
  if yay_or_nah == "stick" && total(hand) < 21
    puts "Sorry! The sum of the cards you have been dealt is less than 21. You lost this round!"
  else
    deal(hand)
    total(hand)
    playing = true
  end  
end

blackjack
```

What I want to do is limit my player to 2 hits (after the initial first hit, which deals 2 cards). I know this is a totally annoying newbie question but I really would appreciate any feedback that would help me think of the solution in the proper manner.

PS: while I understand how loops work I am STRUGGLING with knowing how and when to implement them … so any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like that?

```
MAX_HITS = 2
hits = 0
loop do
  break if hits > MAX_HITS
  puts "Would you like to hit or stick?"
  …
  else
    hits += 1
    …
  end
end
```